# What is the maximum number of simultaneously existing processes resulting from this program, including the original one?

Tags: c++, c, fork

How can I determine this for the following program?

```
if (fork()){
    if(!fork()){
        if(fork()){
            fork();
        }
    }
}
exit(0);
```

Comment: you can run it and count the number of processes, no?

Comment: None, the code fails to compile :)

Comment: There's no loop, so it can't be a fork bomb.

Answer (score 2):

Five.  The original process, plus one for each fork call.  Add a sleep statement and print call to validate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Process Starting\n");

    if (fork()){
        if(!fork()) {
            if(fork()){
                fork();
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Process Exiting\n");
    sleep(2); // sleep 2 seconds
    return 0;
}
```

I'm asserting you'll see 5 "Process Exiting" statements printed.

Comment: No, after the first fork, the parent process continues with the next fork while the child process branches to exit the program.  Look at the return value of fork.

Comment: @selbie That makes it a race condition. If we have threads 1 through 5, we don't know how quickly thread 2 will continue to live. After the second fork, we don't know how long thread 1 will exist, etc. It is unlikely that all 5 will exist at once, but it really depends on when the OS actually lets the threads do some work, and that is going to vary dramatically based on CPU cores, isn't it?

Comment: @JosephLarson: Since 5 processes are created by that sequence of `fork()` calls, the maximum number of simultaneously existing processes is 5 (if they all exist at the same time).  The number could be smaller, but it won't be bigger.

Comment: @JosephLarson - the OP's question is literally: *what is the maximum number?*  The sleep call is introduced to reliably simulate an opportunity for all processes to be running at the same time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- I agree with you.

Comment: @selbie -- right. The sleep removes the timing issue. I didn't realize that you posted an answer plus a comment to your answer, and was only replying to your comment. I wonder if that was a response to someone else's comment, now disappeared. But if you look at your original answer (which I didn't realize was yours) followed by your first comment, then my comment back to you may make more sense.

Comment: *But if you look at your original answer (which I didn't realize was yours) followed by your first comment, then my comment back to you may make more sense.* - and now I'm completely lost.  :)